# LINQ/EF - How to select range of data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a set of employees `(id, name, age)` in the employee table. 
I want to select a range of employees which are just next & previous to the given ID.

So e.g if employee ids are `{1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 25, 26, 40}` then given an id to search for of 10 and a range of 2. Then it should select the 2 items which come before and after 10.

Output should be `{6, 8, 10, 25, 26}`.

I want to make the fewest possible calls to the database (preferably only one call). I tried writing the LINQ query as follows

The problem is how would I get the value of start index in the following query.

```
 var v = (from x in employeeList
                 where x.ID == itemToSearch
                 select x).ToList().GetRange(index-2,4);
```

Comment: you could load all `employee` and than do an [IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) and with this index you can subselect

Comment: If I have million of item then it would too big list in memory. Can't we make a LINQ query which would give me the range directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
int key=10;
int range=2;

var v= employeeList.GetRange((employeeList.FindIndex(x => x == key) - range), (range + range + 1));
```

this works for me.

Comment: Throws exception if key = 1. Also you have list of Employees, not simple integers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative solution:

```
 var itemIndex = employeeList.IndexOf(itemToSearch);
 var result = employeeList.Select((item, index) => {
                                       var diff = Math.Abs(index - itemIndex);
                                       if(diff <= 2) return item;
                                       else return Int32.MinValue;
                                       })
                           .Where(x => x != Int32.MinValue)
                           .ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = (from x in employeeList select x).ToList().GetRange( 
((int)((from d in employeeList select d.ID).ToList().FindIndex(e => e == itemToSearch))) - 2 , 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in 1 query, because there's no concept of "previous" or "next" record in SQL. It would all depend on how the results are ordered, anyway.

I'm thinking you can:

1. Get up to *n* records before and including the `itemToSearch`
2. Get up to *n* records after and including the `itemToSearch`
3. Get the union of (1) and (2).

Code example:

```
var before = (from x in employeeList
              where x.ID <= itemToSearch
              select x).Take(2);

var after = (from x in employeeList
             where x.ID >= itemToSearch
             select x).Take(2);

var result = before.Union(after);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension method to return range of items around first item matching some predicate:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetRange<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int range)
{
    int itemsToFetch = range * 2 + 1;
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>(range + 1);
    bool itemFound = false;
    int itemsFetched = 0;

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            T current = iterator.Current;

            if (itemFound) // if item found, then just yielding all next items
            {
                yield return current; // we don't need queue anymore
                itemsFetched++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (predicate(current))
                {
                    itemFound = true;

                    while (queue.Any()) // yield all content of queue
                        yield return queue.Dequeue();

                    yield return current; // and item which matched predicate
                    itemsToFetch = range;
                }
                else
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(current);

                    if (queue.Count >= range)
                        queue.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            if (itemsFetched == itemsToFetch)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is simple

```
var result = employeeList.GetRange(e => e.ID == 10, 2);
```

It uses queue to keep track of last items which was checked. When item matching predicate found, all queue content it yielded. Then we return next *range* count of items (if there is enough items in source).

For given ids {1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 25, 26, 40} following data is returned:

```
itemToSearch | range | result
---------------------------------------------
    10           2     { 6, 8, 10, 25, 26 }
    40           2     { 25, 26, 40 }
     1           2     { 1, 4, 5 }
    10           0     { 10 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
var index = 3;
var range = 2;
var query = employeeList
    .Where(c=>c.ID <= index)
    .OrderByDescending(c=>c.ID)
    .Take(range + 1)
    .Union(
             employeeList
               .Where(c=>c.ID >= index)
               .OrderBy(c=>c.ID)
               .Take(range + 1)
         );
```

In EF this will produce something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 2 *
     FROM employee
     WHERE ID <= 3
     ORDER BY ID DESC
     UNION
     SELECT TOP 2 *
     FROM employee
     WHERE ID >= 3
     ORDER BY ID) A
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
                var b = GetRange(a.AsEnumerable(), 2, 2);
                foreach (var i in b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static List GetRange(IEnumerable intList, int current, int range)
            {
                List lst = new List();
                int newCurrent = current;
                for (int i = 0; i  intList, int current)
            {
                return intList.SkipWhile(i => !i.Equals(current)).Skip(1).First();
            }

            private static int GetPrevious(IEnumerable intList, int current)
            {
                return intList.TakeWhile(i => !i.Equals(current)).Last();
            }


        }
```